# Remove combination of string in dataset in Python

Tags: python

I have a dataset in Python where I want to remove certain combinations of words of columnX in a new columnY.

Example of 2 rows of columnX:

```
what is good: the weather what needs improvement: the house
what is good: everything what needs improvement: nothing
```

I want tot delete the following combination of words: "what is good" & "what needs improvement".

In the end the following text should remain in the columnY:

```
the weather the house
everything nothing
```

I have the following script:

```
stoplist={'what is good', 'what needs improvement'}
dataset['columnY']=dataset['columnX'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([item in x.split() if item nog in stoplist]))
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide more detail that "doesn't work"?

Comment: the words are still in the text, instead of being removed.

Comment: What is the value of `nog`?

Comment: If you are getting an error, include it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way without using a regex and to still use apply would be to use a simple function:

```
def func(s):
    for item in stoplist:
        s = s.replace(item, '')
    return s
df['columnY']=df['columnY'].apply(func)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can operate on the columns itself.

```py
df["Y"] = df["X"]

df.Y = df.Y.str.replace("what is good", "")
```

So you would have to do this for every item in your stop list. But I am not sure how many items you have.

So for example

```py
replacement_map = {"what needs improvement": "", "what is good": ""}

for old, new in replacement_map.items():
    df.Y = df.Y.str.replace(old, new)
```

if you need to specify different translations or

```py
items_to_replace = ["what needs improvement", "what is good"]

for item_to_replace in items_to_replace:
    df.Y = df.Y.str.replace(item_to_replace, "")
```

if the item should always be *deleted*.

Or you can skip the loop if you express it as a regex:

```py
items_to_replace = ["what needs improvement", "what is good"]

replace_regex = r"|".join(item for item in items_to_replace)

df.Y = df.Y.str.replace(replace_regex , "")
```

(Credits: @MatBailie & @romanperekhrest)

Comment: `Series.str.replace()` is a good idea, but as it can accept regular expressions, the loop isn't required. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie, added a comment about the regex. That would be a great improvement if the items can be packed in a regex.

Comment: You can always express a list of string literals in a regex, see the answer from @romanperekhrest

Answer (score 2):

In your case the replacement won't happen as the condition `if item not in stoplist` (in `item in x.split() if item not in stoplist`) checks if a single **word** match any **phrase** of the stoplist, which is wrong.
Instead combine your stop phrases into a regex pattern (for replacement) as shown below:

```
df['columnY'] = df.columnX.replace(rf"({'|'.join(f'({i})' for i in stoplist)}): ", "", regex=True)
```

---

```
                                             columnX                columnY
0  what is good: the weather what needs improveme...  the weather the house
1  what is good: everything what needs improvemen...     everything nothing
```